# can't insert area tags into map with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want dynamically add `area` to a `map`. So I do

```
    ....
var area = '<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="'+coors4+'" id="area4">';
alert(area);
$('#number_areas').append(area); 
$('[id*="area"]').mapster('select');  

    .....
   <map name="number_areas" id="number_areas">

   </map>
```

so on alert I get `<area href="#" shape="poly" coords="477,1,572,1,572,96,477,96" id="area4">` but `map` tag is still empty

Comment: How are you checking if it is empty?

Comment: with firebug and `$('[id*="area"]').mapster('select');` should make areas selected